# SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ifconfig, wireless-bridge

I am trying to connect my TP-Link AC600 wireless adapter through the USB port to connect to Kali linux Rolling but I am having issues getting it to show up with `ifconfig`

```
    root@kali:~# ifconfig
    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.139  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 0000::000:0000:0000:0000  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 125  bytes 20180 (19.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 72  bytes 14284 (13.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    root@kali:~#
```

Note: I intentionally set the MAC address and inet6 to all 0's for posting this.

I know it exists because i ran `iwconfig`:

```
    root@kali:~# iwconfig
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    ra0       Ralink STA  

    root@kali:~#
```

I tried to bring it up but I got an error:

```
    root@kali:~# ifconfig ra0 up
    SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
    root@kali:~#
```

I have confirmed that kali knows my adapter is plugged in:

```
    root@kali:~# lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    root@kali:~#
```

I never used to have this problem with my old wifi adapter Edimax N150.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Edit:

This is the output of my linux version:

```
    root@kali:~# cat /proc/version
    Linux version 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 
    20170321 (Debian 6.3.0-11) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04)
```

Output of `ip link` (again, I censored my MAC Address)

```
    root@kali:~# ip link
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode 
    DEFAULT group default qlen 1
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast 
    state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 01:01:01:01:01:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: ra0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode 
    DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

No output of `iw ra0 scan dump`:

```
    root@kali:~# iw ra0 scan dump
    root@kali:~#
```

It may help to know that I'm running a virtual machine with VirtualBox Version 5.1.20 r114628 (Qt5.6.2) with Guest Additions installed.

Edit 2:
I installed the driver from [this](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u) github repository using the directions in its README file.

When I run `lsmod` the following entry appears in the list:

```
    mt7650u_sta           913408  0
```

This is what I get when I run `airmon-ng`:

```
    root@kali:~# airmon-ng

    PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

    Warn ON: USB
    null    ra0     ??????      Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Here is what appears after I run `dmesg --follow` and then plug in the adapter:

```
    [   96.244532] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    [   96.626526] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=761a
    [   96.626528] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [   96.626529] usb 1-1: Product: WiFi
    [   96.626530] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
    [   96.626531] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
    [   97.370532] rtusb init rt2870 --->
    [   97.370717] 

           === pAd = ffffac2782215000, size = 884464 ===

    [   97.370755] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
    [   97.370843] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
    [   97.374196] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd-                        >WlanFunCtrl:0x0, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000002
    [   97.407040] MCUType = 2
    [   97.413761] NVM is EFUSE
    [   97.413763] Endpoint(8) is for In-band Command
    [   97.413764] Endpoint(4) is for WMM0 AC0
    [   97.413764] Endpoint(5) is for WMM0 AC1
    [   97.413765] Endpoint(6) is for WMM0 AC2
    [   97.413765] Endpoint(7) is for WMM0 AC3
    [   97.413766] Endpoint(9) is for WMM1 AC0
    [   97.413766] Endpoint(84) is for Data-In
    [   97.413767] Endpoint(85) is for Command Rsp
    [   97.413962] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870
```

Here is what appears in `dmesg --follow` after I attempt `ifconfig ra0 up`.
It seems that at the end an error occurs due to a firmware problem:

```
    [  452.409459] -->RTUSBVenderReset
    [  452.412895] <--RTUSBVenderReset
    [  452.417861] fw version:0.1.00 
    [  452.417862] build:7640
    [  452.417862] build time:
    [  452.417862] 2
    [  452.417863] 0
    [  452.417863] 1
    [  452.417863] 3
    [  452.417864] 0
    [  452.417864] 8
    [  452.417864] 2
    [  452.417865] 2
    [  452.417865] 1
    [  452.417865] 6
    [  452.417866] 5
    [  452.417866] 5
    [  452.417866] _
    [  452.417866] _
    [  452.417867] _
    [  452.417867] _

    [  452.417868] ilm length = 68780(bytes)
    [  452.417868] dlm length = 11476(bytes)
    [  452.499268] #
    [  452.584208] #
    [  452.669704] #
    [  452.751712] #
    [  452.835845] #
    [  452.921746] #
    [  453.002859] #
    [  453.086978] #
    [  453.171254] #
    [  453.254671] #
    [  453.259703] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,                 ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x800,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  453.259703] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  453.339791] #
    [  453.425475] #
    [  453.511495] #
    [  453.595779] #
    [  453.678897] #
    [  453.762715] #
    [  453.846344] #
    [  453.930761] #
    [  454.015048] #
    [  454.101210] #
    [  454.106299] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x9a0,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  454.106299] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  454.187120] #
    [  454.271227] #
    [  454.356669] #
    [  454.438907] #
    [  454.522086] #
    [  454.606318] #
    [  454.691650] #
    [  454.774580] #
    [  454.861492] #
    [  454.946881] #
    [  454.951937] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x9a4,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  454.951937] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  455.030339] #
    [  455.113684] #
    [  455.198504] #
    [  455.281715] #
    [  455.366429] #
    [  455.457864] #
    [  455.541956] #
    [  455.627037] #
    [  455.712217] #
    [  455.793512] #
    [  455.798542] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x9c4,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  455.798542] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  455.877982] #
    [  455.961774] #
    [  456.045695] #
    [  456.131480] #
    [  456.215752] #
    [  456.297832] #
    [  456.382229] #
    [  456.465221] #
    [  456.549737] #
    [  456.635715] #
            [  456.640787] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0xa6c,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  456.640787] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  456.719216] #
    [  456.801377] #
    [  456.889631] #
    [  456.976462] #
    [  457.061738] #
    [  457.144773] #
    [  457.228654] #
    [  457.313486] #
    [  457.397397] #
    [  457.481365] #
    [  457.486455] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN,         Req=0x7, Idx=0x238,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  457.564521] #
    [  457.648699] #
    [  457.732465] #
    [  457.817127] #
    [  457.900727] #
    [  457.984601] #
    [  458.068554] #
    [  458.152929] #
    [  458.236699] #
    [  458.321164] #
    [  458.326274] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x238,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  458.326275] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  458.405021] #
    [  458.489897] #
    [  458.575184] #
    [  458.660094] #
    [  458.747811] #
    [  458.832438] #
    [  458.915785] #
    [  458.999740] #
    [  459.084463] #
    [  459.168569] #
    [  459.173586] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x238,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  459.173586] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  459.173590] loading fw
    [  459.255437] #
    [  459.341691] #
    [  459.426935] #
    [  459.512550] #
    [  459.595554] #
    [  459.682797] #
    [  459.769404] #
    [  459.851295] #
    [  459.939827] #
    [  460.023352] #
    [  460.028362] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x42, Idx=0x230,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  460.028363] set fce dma descriptor fail
    [  460.108241] #
    [  460.195122] #
    [  460.280030] #
    [  460.367394] #
    [  460.455716] #
    [  460.538948] #
    [  460.623427] #
    [  460.711544] #
    [  460.795256] #
    [  460.878787] #
    [  460.883846] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0,         ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6, Idx=0x800,pAd->Flags=0x0
    [  460.883847] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [  460.883848] ERROR!!! 
    [  460.883848] NICLoadFirmware failed, Status[=0x00000001]
    [  460.883849] !!! rt28xx init fail !!!
```

Comment: It doesn't show up because it's in the "down" state, use `ifconfig -a` instead, or even better, the newer `ip link`. Do you get any sensible output with `iw ra0 scan dump` (as root)? Also, please edit your question with information about your kernel version (`cat /proc/version`).

Comment: @dirkt I added the information you asked for at the end of my post.

Comment: Does the problem also appear if you use the WLAN adapter not inside a virtual machine? (So far my guess is either "driver problems/bugs" or "driver doesn't like being virtualized"). Are you using the manufcaturer provided driver, as there seems to be [no direct support](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T2U)?

Comment: @dirkt There is no problem if I use my old adapter as it would come up in `ifconfig` as "wlan0" and works perfectly. I was thinking the same thing about not having a driver because I never installed one on my virtual machine. I just plugged it in like I did with my old one expecting it to work. If this is the case and there is no driver installed, can you please provide me with a link to the correct driver for my Linux version?

Comment: @dirkt ok so I installed the driver from github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u the way it says to in its README file. When I run lsmod I get a listing called mt7650u_sta. When I run airmon-ng I get what I edited on to the bottom of my post.

Comment: @dirkt The TP-Link works fine outside the virtual machine on Windows 10. I just need to get the interface "up" in Kali. I intend to put it in monitor mode for pen testing.       P.S. sorry for the spam

Comment: Look at `dmesg`, you may be missing firmware.

Comment: @DanielB what would show up in `dmesg` if i were missing firmware?

Comment: It will complain about missing firmware, of course. Please disconnect the device from your PC, start `dmesg --follow` and plug it in again. Provide all output starting from “new high-speed USB device number X using ehci-pci”.

Comment: @DanielB ok I added the output of `dmesg --follow` at the end of my post

Comment: Oh wow. Where did you even procure that driver? Well, no matter. Get a different WiFi dongle. For improved chances, get one without 11ac. Alternatively you could try [this patched driver](https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes), it apparently supports your dongle.

Comment: @DanielB I installed the driver you provided a link for but now `dmesg --follow` says "INFO: task ifconfig:1658 blocked for more than 120 seconds. Tainted: G        W  O    4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message." I cannot even run `ifconfig` anymore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
sudo ifconfig ra0 up
```

Use sudo before your command and it will work.

If you are using eth0 or wlan0,

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up/down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up/down
```

This will work as well and doesn't give a message saying Operation not permitted

Comment: How can this possibly be the answer when the question showed that the `ifconfig ra0 up` command was already being run as root?